# Android SDK download with Eclipse, getting error message: Failed to create directory C:/

Tags: android, sdk

Why does this happen? It doesn't matter which package I pick, always the same error message:

```
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 3
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp
```

Comment: run the sdk manager as administrator.it worked for me!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Make sure you have writing permissions for that folder. Try starting Eclipse or the SDK Manager as Administrator.

Comment: Interesting... didn't see this early, but this is what i did and it works now!

Comment: Run as admin, that's amateurish. I see why it's necessary because files are copied into Program Files, but isn't that why we have installers?

Comment: This worked for me, but why do I have to run as Administrator?  Seems like a sloppy workaround to me!

Answer (score 10):

You only have to run SDK Manager as Administrator, right click and select Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 6):

If you put the Android SDK (or anything else) in Program Files, Windows will, by default, require Admin access to edit files in it. But you can change that by changing the folder permissions:

In Windows, right click on the android SDK folder, click Properties. Go to the Security tab, click Edit to change the permissions. Select normal Users and check the box to Allow Full control.

Then, applications that you launch as a normal user will be able to edit the SDK, such as to update it or compile libraries in it.

Answer (score 5):

Please whether the directory `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp` is already there. If there you see the `temp` folder then delete the `temp` folder and try again. It will be installed then.

Comment: i think the problem was "run as administrator" thanks anyway!

Comment: This solved my problem. On Mac, when trying to install everything initially, the permissions were not allowing it. After changing the permissions to allow the directory to be writable, it appears that the `temp` directory was there (but you couldn't `cd` into it). Removing the `temp` directory and retrying worked. It was a combination of permissions, and due to the initial failed attempt, the corrupt `temp` directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the folder `/temp` didn't exist for me, so I just created it and then all was fine.

Yes, after that you need to run android SDK as administrator to download the API/platforms.

If anything looks strange (like a list of incomplete names) no worry, close it, and reopen it after 10sec.

Comment: The folder didn't exist for me either, and creating it seemed to fix it

Answer (score 1):

You can also try installing Android outside of Program Files.  I usually put it in C:\Android, then there are no permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

Run SDK Manager as Administrator, right click and select run as Administrator. It's one of the amazing things of W7, ;p